# Not Detecting second monitor that using Motherboard instead GPU

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, display

so i've bought a new monitor and, ubuntu not detecting it and i believe its because monitor 1 is connected to GPU with DVI and monitor 2 is connected to motherboard with VGA.
i checked in the Display Settings and Nvidia X Server and both of them not detecting second monitor... Thanks for help. ( i have Ubuntu 17.04 )

Comment: If you have a addon card, the usual setup *disables* the integrated one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i bought new cable to fix it .